# Regex match word with characters before and after the value PHP

Tags: php, regex, expression

I've been searching all day finding a regular expression that looks for a specific word even if there are signs in front or behind.

It should be used for a bad words filter. It must look for exact matches but also with marks around the word

It has to search through an array of bad words

For example:

```
stupid - must match
123stupid - must match
stupid123 - must match
123stupid456 - must match
stupi - must not match (because the bad word is not fully inserted)
```

All I can find so far is looking only at whether the exact word (stupid but not 123stupid) or it also searches the half word (stupi)

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you show any examples of what you have tried?

Comment: I tried `/stupid/` (does not work if there are characters before or behind it. does work if only half of the word is entered). and `/.*stupid.*/` as found here on the site, but same result as /stupid/. also `/^stupid$/` then it no longer works with half the word but still not with characters before or after the word

Comment: This is a bad idea btw : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use

```
preg_match('/stupid/', $string)
```

Comment: unfortunately does not work.
123stupid gives 0 as result, stupi give 1 as a result

Comment: @bryanwardenaar: Impossible, show the code you are using to test this. I suspect you have `if (!preg_match('/stupid/', $string))` or something like that.

Comment: I have this with preg_grep because it's an array: `$matches = preg_grep ('/stupid/', $array); print_r($matches);` it only works if the word half or full matches. nothing happens if there are characters before or after the word.